Continuity of the multiplication and inversion in the definition of topological group
A topological group $(G,\, *\,,\, e,\, {\cal{T}})$ is a topological space $(G,\, {\cal{T}})$ that is also a group whose unity element is $ e$ and both the multiplication
$$
 \mu:\quad G \times G \longrightarrow G\;\;,\quad (x,\, y) \longmapsto x* y
 $$
and inversion
$$
 \zeta:\quad G \longrightarrow G\;\;,\quad x \longmapsto x^{-1}
 $$
are continuous.
QUESTION 1
For $\forall x, y\in G$, consider an open $u_{xy}\ni xy$.
By the continuity of $\mu$, its preimage $\mu^{-1}u_{xy}$ is open in the sense of box topology. (Is that correct?)
Would it then be correct to say that $u_{xy}$ is a direct product of some opens $u_x$ and $u_y$?
QUESTION 2
Now consider a not necessarily open neighbourhood $U_{xy}\ni xy$.
What will the continuity of $\mu$ imply for it?  A neighbourhood, $U_{xy}$ contains an open $u_{xy}$ whose preimage is open. If the answer to Q1 is affirmative, would it be right to say that for any neighbourhood $U_{xy}$ there are opens $u_x$ and $u_y$ such that $u_x u_y\subseteq U_{xy}\,$?
Would it also be possible to say that there are neighbourhoods $U_x$ and $U_y$ such that $U_{xy}\subseteq U_x U_y \,$?
QUESTION 3
For a neighbourhood $U_x$ define a set $
\;U_x^{-1}\equiv\left\{ {x^{\,\prime}}^{\,-1}\,\big{|}\,x^{\,\prime}\in U_x    \right\}\;
$ of all inverses:
$$
U_x^{-1}=\zeta(U_x)\quad\mbox{and}\quad U_x = \zeta(U_x^{-1})\;.
$$
Were $U_x$ open, the continuity of $\zeta$ would warrant the openness of $U_x^{-1}$. Our $U_x$, however, is just a neighbourhood. It contains an open $u_x$ whose inverse $u^{-1}_x = \zeta (u_x)$ is open and residing in $U_x^{-1}$:
$$
u_x^{-1}\subseteq U_{x^{-1}}\;.
$$
Is that right?

What are your own thoughts, and what did you try to solve these problems?

Question 1 seems equivalent to asking whether every open set in the product topology is the product of open sets of the factors; this answer is definitely no (there are lots of open sets in $\Bbb R^2$ that aren't open rectangles, for example).

@GregMartin Many thanks for this useful point. Would it then be correct to say that every open set contains a product of open sets of the factors? Unrelated to this, could you please also have a look at my Question 3 ?

Yes, every open set in a product topology contains a product of open sets—I recommend rereading the definition of the product topology to see why. As for (3): any continuous function $f$ from a space to itself such that $f\circ f$ is the identity is always a homeomorphism, so neighbourhoods are preserved.

@GregMartin I truly appreciate your time and help! If you find a minute to combine your comments into an answer, it will be my pleasure to give it full credit and mark it as "useful".

@GregMartin In this specific situation, is it critical to refer to a product topology instead of a box topology?

No, they are the same for finite cartesian products.

@GregMartin This is what I thought. Thanks a lot for your time and patience. (I am not a pure mathematician, hence my naive questions.)
